# Is $\tau$ is a discrete Topology?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\tau = \{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c,d\},X\}$. where $X= \{ a, b, c, d\}$

Is  $\tau$  is a discrete Topology ?

My attempt : I think yes because here $\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c,d\} and X$ are open set

we know that in discrete , all set are open

Comment: The topology $\tau$ is a **complete** list of the open sets, as it were. The set $\{b\}$ is missing so $(X,\tau)$ is *not* discrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discrete topology is one in which every subset is open. In this case $\{b\}$ is not open , so it is not discrete.

Comment: kavi Sir  why $\{b\}$ is not open ? Im not getting

Comment: $\tau$ has just four sets in it and those sets are being declared as the only open sets. Any other set is not open in this topology.